# Error al compilar una app y ejecutarla

Tags: android

He realizado una app con API 34

```
android {
compileSdk 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.valhondo.delgado.inventarioinjurios"
    minSdk 26
    targetSdk 34
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Cuando la compilo por primera vez no sale error pero en la segunda vez, me sale este error y como lo puedo quitar (para que me funcione debo de desinstalar la aplicacion en el movil y volverla a instalar))

2024-01-15 09:10:06.280 32373-32373/com.valhondo.delgado.inventarioinjurios E/entarioinjurios: Attempt to load writable dex file: /data/data/com.valhondo.delgado.inventarioinjurios/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex
2024-01-15 09:10:06.284 32373-32373/com.valhondo.delgado.inventarioinjurios E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.valhondo.delgado.inventarioinjurios, PID: 32373
java.lang.SecurityException: Writable dex file '/data/data/com.valhondo.delgado.inventarioinjurios/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex' is not allowed.
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:406)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:128)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:101)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:438)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:387)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:166)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:160)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:130)
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:146)
at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:93)
at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:134)
at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:126)
at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:61)
at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:1051)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:1143)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1428)
at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:3487)
at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:3479)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7539)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2478)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8893)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)